# Assigning variables (variable mutation) in racket

Tags: variables, lambda, scheme, racket, mutability

I have the following function that given an expression, executes it :

```
(define (foo exp0) exp0)
```

If I do the following:

```
(define x 5)
(foo (+ x 4))
(foo (* x 2))
display(x)
```

I would like for display(x) to display 18. Basically, how can I assign the value of the given expression back to the given variable?

Answer (score 2):

First, the `foo` procedure is simply returning the parameter, it's not "executing" it. Answering your question, here's how you can reassign a value in Scheme:

```
(define x 5)
(set! x (+ x 4))
(set! x (* x 2))
(display x)
```

But to tell the truth, that style of programming (mutating variables) is frowned upon in Scheme. I believe this is more idiomatic:

```
(let* ((x 5)
       (y (+ x 4))
       (z (* y 2)))
  (display z))
```

Comment: @user1025948 Your function `foo` isn't called with a variable.  It's called with a value.  When `(foo x)` is evaluated, `foo` is evaluated to produce a procedure, and `x` is evaluated to produce a value, and then the procedure it called with the value.  The body of the procedure doesn't know anything about what form (in this case, `x`) was evaluated in order to produce the value that is passed to the it.  If the body needs to know about that form, you'll need a macro, as shown in [Chris Jester-Young's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19285810/1281433).

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed write such a macro, if you can guarantee that the variable you're updating is always the first operand:

```
(define-syntax foo
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((foo (op var arg ...))
     (set! var (op var arg ...)))))
```